# GZIP response in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

i have an issue with gzipping response content in my app, When my app is running on frontend module, everything works fine, but if it running on backend module, an error appears when i trying to retrieve json contents,
Here's the error i got :

```
 "Error from HTTP-over-RPC proxy: Zlib error"
```

In my code i set the response header content-encoding

```
res.setHeader("content-encoding", "gzip");
```

I tried to remove this header, an it works on backend module, how ever i still not understanding how backend module deals with Gzipping?!!

Answer (score 1):

Appengine gzips content for you automatically. Assuming you're sending a response with a content type of text/* or application/*, just return the content type as normal. Appengine will zip it and change the content type header for you transparently (if the request headers permit it).

If you've already got gzipped content and are just trying to stream it, you may have to raise an issue if you're seeing problems.

Comment: "If you've already got gzipped content and are just trying to stream it, you may have to raise an issue if you're seeing problems."
Yes, that's what i have, actually i think it may add double-gzip on content, the first occurred from my code and the other from appengine, that's why may i got an zlib error on the browser.

Comment: Are you zipping it yourself? Or just streaming from blobstore/gcs/datastore?

Comment: Note: the automatic gzip encoding or responses seems to be done only on the production server, not on the development one.